# Why is the momentum always conserved in elastic collision?

Tags: angular-momentum, momentum, energy-conservation, collision

As the title above, why is the momentum always conserved in elastic collision (no loss of kinetic energy)?
Does it related to the conservation of kinetic energy? If so, how do we prove that?
Further more, can elastic collision release some energy but still obey the conservation of kinetic energy?
If so, where does the energy released come from?
And what about the angular momentum?Why is it conserved?

Comment: Don't think of the conservation rules of collisions as special or separate from those for other interactions. They are the same rules applied to a defined class of systems. The exception is "elastic collitions conserve bulk kinetic energy" which serve to define what we mean by "elastic" (there is afterall no general rule of conservatioj of kinetic energy).

Answer (score 4):

Momentum is conserved in collisions whether they are elastic or inelastic.

Momentum is conserved in a collision regardless of whether KE is conserved.

An elastic collision is defined as one in which the total KE of the colliding bodies is conserved, so any collision that 'releases' energy is by definition not elastic.

There is no requirement for KE to be conserved- there is only a requirement for total energy to be conserved, so KE can be converted to other forms of energy.

Angular momentum is also conserved, regardless of whether collisions are elastic.

The conservation of momentum is a general law- it does not just apply to collisions. It follows from Newtons third law.

Answer (score 0):

Momentum, energy and angular momentum are always conserved. In inelastic collisions macroscopic *kinetic* energy is not conserved.

Answer (score 0):

> As the title above, why is the momentum always conserved in elastic collision (no loss of kinetic energy)?

If there are no external forces acting on a system then the momentum of the system is conserved.
Note that there is absolutely no mention of energy in this statement.

So the answer to your question

> Does it related to the conservation of kinetic energy?

is, no.

> Further more, can elastic collision release some energy but still obey the conservation of kinetic energy?

An elastic collision is one in which kinetic energy is conserved with no mention of any other forms of energy.

> And what about the angular momentum? Why is it conserved?

Same sort of idea as for linear momentum but now one needs to have no external torques acting on the system.

Answer (score 0):

> why is the momentum always conserved in elastic collision (no loss of kinetic energy)?

Momentum is **always** conserved. Both in elastic and non-elastic collisions.

Of all the possible collisions that are possible, some happen to conserve mechanical energy (kinetic and potential). We give those collisions a name and call them **elastic**.

> Does it related to the conservation of kinetic energy? If so, how do we prove that?

Momentum conservation is a result of Newton's 3rd law and is not a consequence of energy conservation.

> Further more, can elastic collision release some energy but still obey the conservation of kinetic energy?

Unclear what you mean here. In elastic collisions kinetic energy is converted into potential elastic energy, which then in turn is converted 100 % back into kinetic energy. If there were energy losses along the way, we wouldn't call the collision elastic.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is elastic or inelastic collision momentum will always conserved, despite of k. E is conserved or not, momentum conservation and k. E conservation of system are two different  things, momentum transfer can make a rest body accelerate where energy transfer can produce several affects like sound, velocity, heat, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple mentions of Newton's 3rd law, but without any elaboration.

Consider a 1-dimensional collision between a tennis ball and a rigid box.  The tennis ball deforms, and eventually the objects are pushed apart.  Maybe the collision took 0.1 seconds.  At any instant during that 0.1 seconds there are equal but opposite forces (Newton's 3rd law).  And since the forces at any instant are equal but opposite, the integrals of the forces over that 0.1 seconds will be equal but opposite.  Those integrals have the same units as momentum.  So if one object has some amount j added to its momentum, the other object will have some amount -j added to its momentum, so the change in total momentum is +j-j=0.  So there is no change in total momentum.

Note:  You don't know what the force curve with respect to time looks like.  But you can figure out what the area under that curve (aka impulse) must be.

In high school physics, 1-dimensional elastic collisions are solved by considering conservation of energy and conservation of momentum.  This gives you two equations and two unknowns (the unknowns are the final velocities).  It typically looks like this:

- $\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2=\frac{1}{2}m_1(v_1')^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2(v_2')^2$
- $m_1v_1+m_2v_2=m_1(v_1')+m_2(v_2')$

Forget about these for a moment.  We will find the final velocities without using these equations.  We will come up with some new equations.

Consider that the two objects in your 1-dimensional elastic collision are the only two objects in space.  And rather than being a 3rd party observer, you are sitting on one of the objects.  You don't know how fast you are moving, from your perspective it looks like you are sitting still.  You will see the other object move toward you, hit you, then move away from you.  It must move away from you at the same speed it moved toward you.  It intuitively couldn't be any other way (I'll just leave it at "intuitive" instead of justifying further).  In other words, the relative velocities before and after the collision must be opposite.  And also the final velocities will be affected by equal but opposite impulses.  This gives you three equations and three unknowns:

- $v_1-v_2=-(v_1'-v_2')$
- $m_1v_1+j=m_1v_1'$
- $m_2v_2-j=m_2v_2'$

And you can solve for the final velocities.  Ultimately these equations are algebraically equivalent to the high school equations.  For example, if you start with the high school equations, and you rearrange the conservation of energy equation so that you can factor each side using the difference of squares, and then you divide each side by a quantity you get from rearranging the conservation of momentum equation, you will get the relative velocity equation.  If you want two equations and you want them to be short, then use the relative velocity equation and the conservation of momentum equation.

You didn't ask about conservation of energy in an elastic collision, but I think it's important to understand.  First you need to understand why the equation for kinetic energy is what it is.  Imagine a guy walks up 10 feet of stairs and drops a hammer.  Now imagine he walks up 20 feet of stairs and drops a hammer.  Twice as much work was applied to the second hammer.  But its final velocity at the ground is not twice as high.  But what matters is the work.  In an elastic collision, whatever work was done to get the objects moving, that work cannot just vanish or increase out of nowhere.  That work must be conserved.  In other words the energy is conserved.  I'm not a physicist, I'm just some guy, but hopefully this helps.